# How to store player name and score in shared preference and display them in list view on completion of the quiz

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-activity

How to store player name and score in `SharedPreferences` and display them in list view on completion of the quiz please help me out.
I can display only one player name and sore on every completion of the quiz..
here is my code

ResultActivity.java

```
public class ResultActivity extends Activity 
{
    ListView lv;
    Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.result);

        SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        //no need for an editor when retrieving
        String mPlayerScore = Integer.toString(mPrefs.getInt("score", 0));
        String name = mPrefs.getString("name", "xcsxsx");

        String [] prgmNameList={name};
        String [] prgmImages={mPlayerScore};

        context=this;
        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, prgmNameList,prgmImages));
        }
}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    String [] result;
    Context context;
    String [] imageId;
      private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public CustomAdapter(ResultActivity ResultActivity, String[] prgmNameList, String[] prgmImages) 
    {

        result=prgmNameList;
        context=ResultActivity;
        imageId=prgmImages;
         inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                 getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return result.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        TextView tv;
        TextView tv1;;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        Holder holder=new Holder();
        View rowView;        
             rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_scores, null);
             holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
             holder.tv1=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);       
         holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
         holder.tv1.setText(imageId[position]); 
        return rowView;
    }

}
```

list_scores.xml with two text views

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

my listview result.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me out on displaying player name and score in list view..

Answer (score 0):

generally i think its a bad idea to save multiple user scores in the shared preferences and id recommend using a sqlite database instead.

but you could still do it with the shared preferences.

first you need to figure out a name for your entries which is supposed to be unique for every player. Since your are using a listview id use a key something like "username_for_position"+position for the username and "score_for_position"+position for the score.

now you need to be able to tell when your list is complete. the simplest approach is to add another value to the shared preferences to save the usercount. But you wont be able to delete users, or at least its not that easy, because you would have to move the tail.

for example if you have 3 users in your shared prefs, and you delete number 1/2 your listview will still try to access them, because it goes from 0 to 2 (index). To avoid empty lines you would have to iterate over all your users and move them 1 id ahead. a lot of overhead. thats why id recommend a Database.